# custom_attributes not returning from Magento 2 REST API

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, rest-api, custom-attributes, webapi

Using the Magento 2 REST API, I was able to successfully create a new product attribute sending a PUT request to V1/products/attributes/{attribute_code}. In the request, I added a value in the custom_attributes object. However, when I got the attribute I created using a GET request to the same endpoint, I noticed the custom_attributes section was not returned. I can't seem to find any endpoint that will return that data. Could someone point me in the right direction? I'm very new to Magento development. If it helps, here's the JSON I used for the PUT request:
`{
  "attribute": {
    "extension_attributes": {
      "is_pagebuilder_enabled": true
    },
  "is_wysiwyg_enabled": false,
  "is_html_allowed_on_front": true,
  "used_for_sort_by": false,
  "is_filterable": true,
  "is_filterable_in_search": true,
  "is_used_in_grid": false,
  "is_visible_in_grid": true,
  "is_filterable_in_grid": false,
  "position": 0,
  "apply_to": [],
  "is_searchable": "0",
  "is_visible_in_advanced_search": "0",
  "is_comparable": "1",
  "is_used_for_promo_rules": "0",
  "is_visible_on_front": "1",
  "used_in_product_listing": "1",
  "is_visible": true,
  "scope": "store",
  "frontend_input": "text",
  "entity_type_id": "4",
  "is_required": false,
    "options": [],
    "is_user_defined": true,
    "default_frontend_label": "string",
    "frontend_labels": [
      {
        "store_id": 0,
        "label": "string"
      }
    ],
  "is_user_defined": true,
  "default_frontend_label": "testing",
  "frontend_labels": [],
  "backend_type": "varchar",
  "backend_model": "Magento\\Eav\\Model\\Entity\\Attribute\\Backend\\ArrayBackend",
  "default_value": "",
  "is_unique": "0",
  "validation_rules": [],
    "custom_attributes": [
      {
        "attribute_code": "test-attr",
        "value": "true"
      }
    ]
  }
}`